# difference between signtool and sn or al for assembly signing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, assembly-signing

I see tool like SN which generates private/public key pair for signing an assembly.
and using AL tool we can assign a strong name to an assembly

And we have also Sign tool which is used for signing the assembly (probably for using with certificates exclusively?).

What is the exact difference between the two?. Is it sign tool have to be used when working with certificates and can it we acheive it SN?. or are they totally different.?

Please help.

Comment: have you tried an internet search? what did you find?

Comment: I didn't find any article so far explaining the differences between the two

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Signtool is to do code signing, which provides code integrity check and authentication of the publisher.

Sn is to do strong name.  It's just for .NET assembly.  It addresses the unique ID issue.

Both tools can make sure the files have not been tampered with but only code signing (signtool) can assure you who is the publisher of the files.

We can use SignTool.exe to sign and time stamp a file with given pfx, even though the file is a strong named dll.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So it means , I can have a separate private/public key for strong naming the assembly and then do signing with sign tool by providing certificate or key (different from earlier one) given signing authorities?. And when we say strong name , it implies digital signature also as one of the part of strong name components right(name,version,culture , public key , digital signature). In this, the digital signature part, will be it the one created with strong naming (sn or al tool) or the one created with sign tool?.

Comment: Also, when I check strong name dll with ildasm, i could see version,public key but not digital signature in the manifest. where is it exactly stored?.

Comment: @sveerap: Yes, you can have prvate/public key for strong name and then do signing with signtool.  Your strong name is using the public key/private key created with sn tool.  I didn't try to find out the signature and I don't know whether they are in manifest or not.  To specify the strong name, you don't really need to know the digital signature.  Why do you want to find it out?

Comment: @sveerap: Your question on where the digital signature of SN makes me can't fall asleep :).  I just found out the answer from CLI spec.  http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf.  See page 189 section 25.3.3.  The SN digital signature is stored in one of the extended section of the PE file format.  This is used by CLI loader only.  Again, you don't really need it to in your strong name.